# Error with deleted user when using OneSignal

Tags: flutter, dart, onesignal

I deleted a user from OneSignal and now the app is giving this error:

```
OneSignalRestClient: POST RECEIVED JSON: {"errors":["not a valid device_type"]}
Failed last request. statusCode: 400
response: null
```

I tried deleting and reinstalling the app, but it didn't work, I also tried flutter clean. What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you delete a user, there is no way to recover them and it may cause issues with analytics and tracking. Please read our documentation on deleting users
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/users-and-devices#section-how-do-i-delete-several-unsubscribed-users-from-the-all-users-page-

Comment: I deleted the user in the OneSignal page by going to Options>Delete. I thought this was convenient. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you make a request

```
http.Response response = await http.get("your_url_here");
if (response == null || (response != null && response.statusCode == 400)) {
  // here you can consider user account to be deleted. 
} else {
  // proceed as you would
}
```

Comment: But I think that the error is coming from the OneSignal.init() or something, and I want that user that is stored in the server to re add it to OneSignal. So where can I add these conditions that you are referring to?

Comment: @inoi Do you want to re-add the user? If that's what you need, then this answer wont' help! I thought you were having issues with the URL request for deleted user.

Comment: Yes I want to re-add the user. I only deleted it because I wasn't getting OneSignal notifications for some reason, so I thought if a re-do everything from the beginning it might work again, because in other devices it's working.

Answer (score 0):

When you install the app the data is not cleared, so what I did was I cleared the data and cache of the application by going to AppInfo and selecting Storage. After that it functioned. This functions in Android, but it must be something like this even in IOS.